# Why does this code turning out to be an infinite loop?

Tags: python, string, while-loop, find, substring

I am trying to write a code that finds the position of the sub string, given a string. I believe there is some issue in the looping, it is turning out to be an infinite loop.

```
string="ABCDCDC"
sub_str="CDC"
i=0
while i<len(string):
    if sub_str in string:
        i=string.find(sub_str,i)
        print("Position is {}".format(i))
    else:
        break
    i+=1
```

Actual Output I'm getting:

```
Position is 2
Position is 4
Position is -1
Position is 2
Position is 4
Position is -1
Position is 2
Position is 4
Position is -1
```

Expected Output:

```
Position is 2
Position is 4
```

Comment: Think about your loop for a moment. You are overwriting `i`, the value that is also meant to handle the length of the string, in order to hold the substring position. It will always reset back to either 2 or 4. As a result, `i` will always be less than `len(str)`.

Comment: `sub_str in string`, if true once, will always be true, because you never change the value of `string`. Only `find` takes into account the current value of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting 'i' and hence it becomes an infinite loop. Secondly, you can use a list to keep a reference of your indexes (that meet your success criteria) in order to avoid re-printing of indexes as well as -1. Here's an improvement to your code.

```
string = "ABCDCDC"
sub_str = "CDC"
i = 0
list = []
size = len(string)
while i < size:
    if sub_str in string:
        pos = string.find(sub_str, i, size)
        if pos != -1 and pos not in list:
            print("Position is {}".format(pos))
            list.append(pos)
    else:
        break
    i += 1
```

Comment: Oh yeah it is because of the condition "if sub_str in string", its always true,its going in an infinite loop, 
string="ABCDCDC"
sub_str="CDC"
i=0
while i<len(string):
    i=string.find(sub_str,i)
    if i!=-1:
        print("Position is {}".format(i))
    else:
        break
    i+=1